# Regular Expression to match alphanumeric, non alphanumeric and spaces

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match strings containing alphanumeric, non alphanumeric characters (simple punctuation marks including underscores, hyphens and decimal points) and spaces in my input file and then print them to a separate file.

Here's an example of the string:

```
ID123 MIR24-2 10.6
```

I can search for individual items in the string but nothing that ties the whole lot together including the spaces.

I've tried:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9_-]*[-0-9.0-9]*$/
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this? If you don't have any possible format for the string!!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'll edit it.

Comment: So what are you NOT matching?  You've just about said you want to match everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand well your needs, but is this regex work for you?

```
$str =~  /\w+\s[\w-]+\s\d+\.\d+/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that `^[A-Za-z\d\s-]*$`

Answer (score 0):

Try regex something like this `/^[\w+\d\s-]+$/i`.
Are there any patterns like it'll contain at least 1 space etc.?

Comment: Yes, the format of the input file is: text and/or numbers and/or non-alphanumeric characters, space, text and/or numbers and/or non-alphanumeric characters, space, space and text and/or numbers and/or non-alphanumeric characters.